# Restart timer for a device

Tags: timer

I have a device which needs to be manually restarted (switched off and back on) after every 4 hours or so. I was wondering if there is some device which I can buy or make which does this work for me.

Sorry if this question does not belong here, I am new to this. If it is inappropriate just tell me and I will remove the question

Comment: You need to provide more details if you expect a useful answer. For example, does the device use ordinary house power (120 or 240 volts)?  In that case, there are many types of timers readily available at hardware stores and home centers that could do what you want.  How long a period must the timer operate: 12 hr, 24 hr, 1 week, etc.

Comment: If you wanted to (say) remove power from a device every 3.5-4.5 hours for a handful of seconds, that could be made from a TLC555+CD4040 plus some diodes and transistors and a relay, but I fear that might be a bit much to bite off.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, May I ask details of the configuration you are referring to?

Comment: @Barry The device I am talking about is a automatic water motor device, it operates at normal household potential difference of 240V and I need the timer to work round the clock and reset after every 3 or 4 hours

Comment: I don't get some of the close votes here. There was an initial close vote, since it appeared the OP was looking for a recommendation for a specific product (he also mentioned making something.) I understand that vote, since it was before my answer. However I made it clear in the first paragraph of my answer it was unlikely the OP would be able to find a commercial device, and instead presented a circuit he could build. And then comes along a **second** close vote based on "looking for a recommendation for a specific device". Did the second person voting to close even bother to read my answer?

Comment: Does the off period matter? Would switching off for 15 minutes every 4 hours be a problem? If not, cheap household mechanical timers would do.

Comment: @BrianDrummond As I indicated in my answer, there are commercial timers available. Besides the more expensive electronic ones that can have periods as short as one minute, I mentioned there are cheaper mechanical ones.  However he needs a 240 VAC one rated for appliances, like [this one](http://www.amazon.com/Intermatic-HB112C-Heavy-Conditioner-Appliance/dp/B000AY3OZ4/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1403521745&sr=8-2&keywords=240v+appliance+timer) and they typically have a fixed number of on-off periods -- he would need 12 pegs. Any type of device like this may be too expensive for him to buy in India.

Comment: Yeah but the American ones seem ridiculously overpriced compared to this : It really doesn't make sense to build one. http://www.amazon.co.uk/Electronic-digital-mains-Socket-Display/dp/B002P7RF9A/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1403524284&sr=8-1&keywords=mains+timer  Or for a mechanical one with no need for pegs : http://www.amazon.co.uk/CostMad-Mechanical-Segmented-Adjustable-Programme/dp/B007PF5ZT4/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1403524284&sr=8-2&keywords=mains+timer

Comment: @BrianDrummond I agree the first one with the LCD looks pretty good if he can get it sent to India for a reasonable price, and the one minute off time is acceptable.

Comment: @tcrosley I agree with you, the question specifically refers to "a device I can buy ***or make***..." That's why I didn't vote to close. However, it is still fairly broad/vague. (Though I didn't vote any particular way.)

Comment: If an electronic circuit is not to your liking. In Australia I can get electro mechanical devices that have a circular face and a series of holes on the perimeter. You place pegs in holes corresponding to the turn on/off times. I use it for various things like lamps etc It drifts by a few minutes a month but you can set it to turn on/off at anything from every 5 mins to once per 24hrs....

Answer (score 2):

There are commercial timers that will do what you want, but they are quite expensive, even in the US; for example this one -- TORK Electronic Timer # E101B 120-277V SPST --is [$74 from Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00D6C7EK8).  (Intermatic makes a less expensive appliance timer, but since the on/off periods are set mechanically, I don't think you can get a small enough off period).

Circuit wise, it is not too difficulty to make your own using a 555 chip configured as an astable multivibrator.

[image]

Use Right-Click View Image to see a larger version of this schematic.

The values for R1 and R2 and C1 are selected such that the on time is 4 hours (240 minutes), and the off time is five seconds.  If the latter is too short, you can calculate new values [here](http://home.cogeco.ca/~rpaisley4/555.html) (scroll down to the ASTABLE OSCILLATOR CALCULATOR).  The times are not going to be that accurate though, due to the tolerance of the 4700 µF capacitor.  So you may have to fine-tune the circuit after building.

The hardest to find part will be the relay; I found one [at Digi-Key](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/G4W-2212P-US-TV5-HP-DC12/Z3693-ND/1815535) that has a 12v coil, and is rated at 7.5A inductive at 250 VAC.  I doubt if you are going to try getting that exact one since you are in India, but you will need to look for one that meet your switching requirements (you didn't mention them, so I just guessed).

**BE VERY CAREFUL** wiring the section for 240 VAC, this voltage is lethal.  I would build the circuit, and then test it (without being plugged into the 240 VAC mains) by using a voltmeter across each of the contacts.

Comment: Umm... 238 seconds << four hours, n'est-ce pas?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany   Whoops, that's just a little under 4 minutes, my bad.  Thanks for catching that.  l'll update the schematic.

Comment: TCrosley's cautions wrt working with the mains are well worth noting.

Answer (score 2):

You asked for details of a configuration involving a TLC555 + 4040 + some discretes. I will give you all the information that you need to complete the design with a little work and some basic math.

There are four blocks to the circuit, each of which is a more-or-less independent design. If you have detailed questions, I suggest you open a new question for each block where you have an issue.

1. Power supply. I suggest a regulated wall wart which supplies 12V at 1A (the circuit will only use 200mA or less). Easily scavenged or you can buy one. You could also use a transformer, rectifier, filter, 7812, but it's hardly worth it.
2. Oscillator. I suggest a [TLC555 astable multivibrator](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc555.pdf) configuration. 
   A period of about 3.5 seconds is required. I got that by dividing four hours \$\times\$ 3600 seconds by \$2^{12}\$ since the CD4040 is a 12-bit counter. Something like 10uF for Ct, 470K for RA and 39K for RB. Check the formulas in the datasheet and confirm my arithmetic. That should give a total period of 3.5 seconds, approximately. If you use an electrolytic for CT, a low-leakage or tantalum type is preferred, but most any leaded electrolytic will probably work okay (IME surface mount types tend to be leakier). You don't need RL and CL, but the 100nF on pin 5 is a good idea, as is the 100nF bypass across the power supply. Use one of those across the counter power supply too.

   [image]
3. Counter. I suggest a [CD4040](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Fairchild%20PDFs/CD4040.pdf)

   [image]

Connect the clock to the output (pin 3) of the TLC555. The reset input can be connected via an RC to +12 as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVzgpv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The circuit will produce a short (around 100msec) pulse when power is applied to reset the counter so the first "off" period (after the initial one!) will happen 4 hours from application of power.

4.OR circuit and relay driver.. I'll assume the relay is energized for output "ON". You could reverse the logic and have it de-energized and use the normally-closed contact.

Here, I suggest taking outputs Q1 to Q12 and connecting them through diodes and discretes as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhU1sw.png)</sup>

The counter proceeds in sequence from 0x000 to 0xFFF in binary. As drawn, the outputs Q1 to Q12 are all low only one 3.5 second period in 14336 seconds. If that is too short a time, you can remove diode D1 to give you 7 seconds "off", or remove D1 **and** D2 to give you 14 seconds off. Review the operation of a binary counter to see how this works.

Comment: So the idea with that last schematic is that once all the diodes becomes reverse biased the divider will have its input source removed and as such Q3 is turned off and the relay opens? Very simplistic, yet effctive. I understand everything but that second schematic you have shown - what exactly is it for and how does it work?

Comment: Yes, you've got it right. The reset circuit- if you imagine the capacitor discharged, when power is applied the RESET output goes high while the capacitor charges to 12V. When power is removed, it discharges through whatever load is on the power supply (usually there's an LED if the relay isn't on). R2 prevents too much current going through the protection network in the 4040. This is a really cr*p reset circuit, BTW, but it's not unusual in consumer goods.

Comment: My only question is that with 5V logic you are limiting the current through that divider to be 360uA assuming 700mV drop across `R1`. Therefore, assuming maybe half of the diodes may be active at any time, we'll have (approximately) 60uA through each diode. Which leads me to beleive such a state is impossible since the Vd of a diode with a forward current of 60uA is likely to be close to 0V which is further means that Q3 is not active and the relay is open. Also, the datasheet states that 88mA can be sourced from the CD4040, so would this be safe or should be drive transistors with the output?

Comment: I was assuming 12V power for everything, so CD4040 not 74HC4040. There is a 1.2V voltage drop from Vbe and Vf of a diode, so maybe 10V across the resistor, so 2mA into the base, roughly. That means that a relay as power-hungry as a T90 type should be okay (77mA coil current). The base current is pretty much independent of the number of outputs that are on- unless none are on, of course. Maybe 1.8mA for 1 output and 2.1 mA for all 12, something like that. If you look at the output curves for the 4040 you can predict it.